# How to build to subfolders within Visual Studio's intermediate directory?

Tags: c, visual-studio, project-settings

Essentially, the project I'm working with contains *many* files with the same name, separated only by directories.

```
/src/dir1/file.c
/src/dir2/file.c
/src/dir3/file.c
```

and so on. I recognize this probably isn't good practice but this isn't my codebase. When compiling I understandably get this warning:

```
warning MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of file.c will produce outputs to the same location.
```

I'm wondering if there's some way to build the .o files to an identical folder structure within Visual Studio's specified "Intermediate Directory", like this:

```
/x64/Debug/dir1/file.o
/x64/Debug/dir2/file.o
/x64/Debug/dir3/file.o
```

which would negate the need to manually rename dozens of these files.

I'm not overly familiar with manipulating the project settings within VS, so I'm not even sure if this is possible. The codebase was previously compiled with gcc, specifying a separate output directory for each file with the same name.

Comment: Answer I was looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729515/visual-studio-2010-2008-cant-handle-source-files-with-identical-names-in-diff

Comment: Try to include syntax highlighting in code blocks.